# ajax in wordpress: avoid wp-admin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to trigger ajax requests on wordpress frontend in order to get some custom response. lets say to get next/previous post-ID in JSON format.
In production environment the wp-admin directory is inacccessible for http requests by htaccess.

Whats the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: you have already coded the required hooks ??

Comment: you mean via add_action('wp_ajax_avoid_admin', 'fn_avoid_admin')? No i havent cause ajax_url has to be sthing like '/wp-admin/' or am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

Because AJAX is already used in WordPress’ back end, it has been basically implemented for you. All you need to do is use the functions available. Let’s look at the process in general before diving into the code.

Every AJAX request goes through the admin-ajax.php file in the wp-admin folder. That this file is named admin-ajax might be a bit confusing. I quite agree, but this is just how the development process turned out. So, we should use admin-ajax.php for back-end and user-facing AJAX.

Each request needs to supply at least one piece of data (using the GET or POST method) called action. Based on this action, the code in admin-ajax.php creates two hooks, wp_ajax_my_action and wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action, where my_action is the value of the GET or POST variable action.

Adding a function to the first hook means that that function will fire if a logged-in user initiates the action. Using the second hook, you can cater to logged-out users separately.

Comment: The file admin-ajax.php is located under /wp-admin/ right? This directory is completely locked due to htacess protection "deny from all". Thats a requirement of the client. Could you imagine another solution to perform an ajax request?

Comment: Get Firebug and see what status it is showing on console when ajax is called.